# Issue in Python lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is my code:

```
list_b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

print (list_b)
if(1 in list_b):
    t=list_b.append('hello')
    print(t)

else:
    t1=list_b.append(100)
    print(t1)
```

In the console it is showing me `None`. ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKymy.png))

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append()` method does not return any value but updates existing list.
if you want to see the updated list, use `print(list_b)`.
`print(t)` or `print(t1)` will return `None` as they don't have any return values.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated the issue, but I'm assuming it's this:

```py
t=list_b.append('hello')
```

`append()` modifies the array, it doesn't return a new array.